# How can I change the data-url attribute of a Bootstrap Modal div?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a modal to apply filters to a data table.  There can be many filters applied, therefore each time the user clicks "Add Filter", the modal window needs to be aware of previous filters.  I am doing this through a query string parameter, therefore each time the user clicks "Save Changes" in the modal window, I need to update the data-url attribute.

Here is the modal:

```
<!-- Filter Table Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFilter" tabindex="-1" data-url='@Url.Action("ApplyFilter", new { page = Model.PagingInfo.CurrentPage, sortOrder = Model.SortOrder, view = Model.View, encodedFilters = FilterHelper.EncodeFilterObject(Model.Filters) })' role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="modalFilterContainer"></div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code to post to the server and update the HTML on the page with the data returned:

```
$(document).on('click', '#saveFilterChanges', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $('#formApplyFilters').attr('action');

    $.post(url, { 
            ColumnName: $('#ColumnName').val(), 
            FilterOperator: $('#FilterOperator').val(), 
            Param1: $('#Param1').val(),
            Param2: $('#Param2').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        //replace page parts
        $('#mainPageTable thead').replaceWith($(data).find('#mainPageTable thead'));
        $('#mainPageTable tbody').replaceWith($(data).find('#mainPageTable tbody'));
        $('#mainPageTablePager').replaceWith($(data).find('#mainPageTablePager'));
        $('#sideBarInfo').replaceWith($(data).find('#sideBarInfo'));
        $('#filterList').replaceWith($(data).find('#filterList'));
        $('#phaseViews').replaceWith($(data).find('#phaseViews'));

        var newUrl = $(data).find('#modalFilter').attr('data-url');
        $('#modalFilter').prop('data-url', newUrl);

        //hide filter
        $('#modalFilter').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

As you can see, I have tried a few different things.  The simplest test was adding a "title" attribute to the modal div, and trying to get the title.  This doesn't work.  So I'm guessing that Bootstraps JS code does something to this element that prevents it from being accessed in the DOM??

EDIT: The first 6 "replaceWith" calls (up to #phaseViews) work fine, so the post to the server is working and returning the correct data.

Essentially, I want to take the new data-url that is passed back in the jQuery post from the server, and update the modal div on the page, so that the new encodedFilters parameter is updated.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How many such elements do you have in `data`? If severals - think about some refactoring, since multiple elements with the same ID is not right. If one - why `each`?

Comment: Add `$('#modalFilter').` wouldn't work, since `#modalFilter` is not on the page yet. Or is there some other element with such ID already there?

Comment: `$(data)` that is being returned from the server contains the entire HTML page.  All this works fine when I disable Javascript.  But if I want to update only parts of the page (rather than refreshing the whole screen), I can't seem to update the modal portion.

How come the `#modalFilter` element is not on the page yet?  If I put a break point at `var newUrl` and look at the $(data) object, I can see the `#modalFilter` element in there.  I just cant' access the `'data-url'` attribute.